# Gremlin Traversal

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, tinkerpop

**EDITED**: After @Prashant answer I understood order of my output needs to be preserved, so accordingly I have edited my original question and reposted.

Below is my graph:
[image]

```
g.addV('person').property(id, 1)
g.addV('person').property(id, 2)
g.addV('person').property(id, 3)
g.addV('person').property(id, 4)
g.addV('person').property(id, 5)
g.addV('person').property(id, 6)
g.addV('person').property(id, 7)
g.addV('person').property(id, 8)
g.addV('person').property(id, 9)
g.addV('person').property(id, 10)
g.addV('person').property(id, 11)
g.addV('person').property(id, 12)
g.addV('product').property(id, 13)
g.V(2).addE('related').to(V(1))
g.V(2).addE('related').to(V(5))
g.V(5).addE('related').to(V(6))
g.V(5).addE('related').to(V(7))
g.V(5).addE('related').to(V(9))
g.V(7).addE('related').to(V(8))
g.V(9).addE('related').to(V(4))
g.V(9).addE('related').to(V(10))
g.V(4).addE('related').to(V(3))
g.V(10).addE('related').to(V(11))
g.V(10).addE('related').to(V(12))
g.V(1).addE('chose').to(V(13))
g.V(8).addE('chose').to(V(13))
g.V(9).addE('chose').to(V(13))
g.V(3).addE('chose').to(V(13))
g.V(11).addE('chose').to(V(13))
g.V(12).addE('chose').to(V(13))
```

I want to traverse from root node (2) to leaf nodes (1, 6, 8, 3, 11 and 12). While such traversal I want to fetch nodes which are connected to product node 13 ie) I wish to write a query which returns 1, 8, 9 3, 11 and 12.

@Prashant's answer:

```
g.V().repeat(out().simplePath()).until(out().hasLabel("product")).dedup()
```

outputs

```
==>v[1]
==>v[9]
==>v[8]
==>v[3]
==>v[11]
==>v[12]
```

However order of my required output is 1, 8, 9, 3, 11 and 12 ie) at each level, requirement is to pick a child node and traverse all the way to its leaf node. Order of nodes at each level of the tree is guaranteed to be in ascending order. Any help here, please? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Below query should do the job.

```
g.V().repeat(out().simplePath()).until(out().hasLabel("product")).dedup()
```

Comment: When I tried your answer, I realised order of output nodes is significant to my requirement. So I have edited my question. Let me know, if you can help me here? Thanks!!

Comment: @Bala it is not a good practice to rely on the order in which the database is keeping the data. Because different implementation of gremlin servers can keep the different indexes and that can impact the order you get. 
So, If you have a property which can use to order the result set, you would be able to write a query which will give you same order agnostic of server indexes. If not, IMO that you are not doing it right.

Comment: Agreed, I am not relying on indexes. This is a sample question I created to replicate my actual scenario. So to keep it simple here, I am relying on indexes. In my actual case, I would have event creation time ie) 4 (and 3), 10 (and 11, 12) can be swapped but their event creation time property will help me to order the result set.

Comment: in that case, you can append the query in question with `order().by()`. The by step can use the property which you want to use order. does that help what you need ?